# Execution failed for task: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

Could you help me with one Gradle's problem?
In my current project, we use Gradle to build our huge project.
And when I change some lines in my code and try to run my project -> I have an error:

> "Execution failed for task: 'Taskname'
> java.lang.StackOverflowError
> *Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights"

Then I run 2 commands: ".\gradlew clean" and ".\gradlew --stop" and run my project again -> and the project builds successfully.
I used Intellij.

What is wrong that I need each time to clean and stop Gradle?
Is it possible to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the some lines you changed and task your missing with .
And its probably `gradlew --stop` that help with the issue , because `gradlew --clean` will only delete the already built Jar "**build dir**" , which is only related to installed dependency and creating a jar while stop command will be used when you want to explicitly stop running Daemon processes for any reason .

When a function call is invoked by a Java Application, a stack frame is allocated on the call stack. The stack frame contains the parameters of the invoked method, its local parameters, and the return address of the method. The return address denotes the execution point from which, the program execution shall continue after the invoked method returns. If there is no space for a new stack frame then, the StackOverflowError is thrown by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

The most common case that can possibly exhaust a Java application’s stack is recursion. In recursion, a method invokes itself during its execution. Recursion one of the most powerful general-purpose programming technique, but must be used with caution, in order for the StackOverflowError to be avoided.

If you could share the build.gradle file and what did you change we might be able to give more way accurate answer .

Resources : [Java code geeks](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-how-to-solve-stackoverflowerror/)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.

Unfortunately, I can't share the Gradle file because of security policy.
Maybe I try to provide an example of my changes.
So, we have a void that opens the website and goes to one of the tabs.
I add a line that refreshes the page before going to the tab.
And when I try to run code with my changes -> error from the top is returned.

Is it possible that the ".\gradlew clean" command helps?
I mean that when I run this command my project rebuild and that helps?